# Pytest: How to pass method which returns list as an argument in parametrized test

Tags: python, pytest

I have a question regarding parametrizing the test method with another method that returns the list of test data that I want to use in my test:

When I execute code in this way:

```
class Test:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("country_code", get_country_code_list())
    def test_display_country_code(self, country_code):
        print(country_code)

    @classmethod
    def get_country_code_list(cls) -> list:
        return [1, 2, 3]
```

I get error: Unresolved referency: get_country_code_list. It doesn't make a difference if get_country_code_list method is a static method, class method or self.

But if I put the method get_country_code_list() above the test method, I don't get this error.
Does the order of test methods make a difference in Python?

Comment: Why is it a class method? Just make it a regular function, at module scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the order in which you do things is important.

Functions are just like variables in that manner.

Working Example Variables

```
x = 3
y = 5
z = x + y
```

Works perfectly fine, because everything is done according to order.

Broken Example Variables

```
x = 3
z = x + y
y = 5
```

Doesn't work, of course, because y is neither declared nor defined when y is needed for the initialization of z.

Works just the same with functions

```
def bar():
    return foobar()

def foo():
    return bar()

foo()

def foobar()
    return 5
```

Function `foo` can call function `bar` perfectly fine, but `bar` can't call foobar, because foobar is not defined yet at the execution point of foo().

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a test-specific issue only.

You need to understand that `@pytest.mark.parametrize` is a [decorator](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/decorators-python), a *syntactic sugar* of a class / method. When you pass an argument in a class / method, it expects the argument to be defined. Hence why this works:

```py
def display(arg):
  return print(arg)

word = "Hello World!"
display(word)
```

while this does not:

```
def display(arg):
  return print(arg)

display(word)
word = "Hello World!"
```

Here's an example of a class-based decorator:

```
class MyDecorator:
  def __init__(self, decor_arg):
    self.decor_arg = decor_arg

  def __call__(self, fn):
    def wrapper(fn_arg):
      return fn_arg
    return self.decor_arg

def message(arg):
  return f"The parameter passed is {arg}"

@MyDecorator(message)
def display(arg):
  return arg

print(display("Hello World!"))
```

The print result:

```bash
The parameter passed is Hello World!
```

Given the explanation above, I'm sure you can see why the method `message` needs to be placed before `display`. If your editor has IntelliSense, changing the order of the two methods will display an error outline on `@MyDecorator(concat)` with the message "*undefined name 'message'*" or something similar.